# Is it possible to combine several modules into one module in gcc?

Tags: gcc, module

Say I have `a.o` and `b.o` and I want to combine them into `c.o`

in makefilw I wrote:

```
gcc a.o b.o -o c.o
```

but got the error:

```
undefined reference to `main'
```

Why did this happen and what is the right solution?

Comment: sorry i forgot to make the layout

Comment: Your method looks correct, but you'l have to add the `-nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs` flags to the linker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to create a (static) *library* or an *archive*. Look for example at http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html or try type `man ar` in your shell :)